# SSRS: Partial re-use of a MDX query? OR MDX as Parameter?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

in Sql Server Reporting Services Report

is it possible to define a MDX query within a report, and then re-use it a bunch of times, but each time with different WHERE section.

i.e. the Members and SELECT section would be the same for each row (MTD.Count YTD.Count)

but, i'd want to filter it 10 different ways..

The only way i can think of doing this right now, is adding 10 datasets, each with a different WHERE section, but i'd like to re-use just one DS

ALTERNATIVELY

Another totally acceptable option would be to supply whole MDX queries to the report as parameters of some sort. My challenge is that my MDX queries are generated dynamically (**including the # of actual queries**), all of that is user driven. So is there a way i could supply n MDX queries to a report, and have it plug that into a matrix? One way i thought of doing this today, is to emit the whole RDL XML dynamically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely my solution:

[Subreports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239314.aspx)

Yep, subreports saved me here.. My actual goal was to repeat the same MDX query with a different WHERE section for each row. Sub reports are design for just that. You can define a matrix and bind it to a dataset. That dataset will determine how many rows of data your matrix will be populated it.

You can embed a subreport in a cell of your matrix, and pass it a parameter (in my case i am passing the whole WHERE filter, but you could make it more granular and only pass a field.

Then in your subreport you can display just one set of information based on a parameter which is passed in from parent report.

here are some more links

[SubReports](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/ReportingServices.aspx)

[Designing Reports with Custom MDX Queries](http://sqlserverbiblog.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/designing-reports-with-custom-mdx-queries-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the dataset using a few parameters like this:

```
SELECT
{
    StrToSet(@rowAxisMdx)
} ON 0,
{
    StrToSet(@columnAxisMdx)
} ON 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE {
    @StrToSet(@slicerAxisMdx)
}
```

It will be slow since you are using a lot of StrToSet functions, but it should work.

Comment: how do you make @slicerAxisMdx different in each row? that is my question.

Comment: meaning, i want more than just one variation of the query.. i need n variations of it. like.. an array of @slicerAxisMdx

Comment: You can do it in subreports, passing different MDX I suppose...you can't change the WHERE clause dynamically in the same query

Comment: yep, subreports ended up being exactly what i needed.. not sure when you added this comment .. sorry if it was before i got to that conclusion in my answer :)

Comment: It wasn't ;) I was just trying to say that you can use subreports with the parameterized MDX as in my answer above if needed - you can pass parameters to the subreports...